# Dynamic Extraction of text - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a column with values in the following format:

```
Successfully refunded 1 units of product 11111111
Successfully refunded 1 units of product 22222222 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 33333333 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 55555555 
Successfully refunded 1 units of product 44444444
Successfully refunded 1 units of product 67676767 
Successfully refunded 1 units of product 90909090 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 36456421
```

how can i extract the number after 'product'.
It is simple to extract when there is one 'product'.

Expected Result:

```
11111111
22222222,33333333,55555555,44444444,
67676767
90909090,36456421
```

Comment: So, you're always looking for the next "word" after the word `'product'` and before the word `'Successfully'` or the end of the value? What have you tried so far? If this, however, is how you're storing your data I would suggest you need to fix your data model (and creating a delimited list isn't the solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get away with a few `REPLACE`:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (TextValues VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Table (TextValues)
VALUES
    ('Successfully refunded 1 units of product 11111111'),
    ('Successfully refunded 1 units of product 22222222 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 33333333 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 55555555 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 44444444'),
    ('Successfully refunded 1 units of product 67676767'),
    ('Successfully refunded 1 units of product 90909090 Successfully refunded 1 units of product 36456421')


SELECT
    Replaced = STUFF(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(T.TextValues, 'Successfully refunded 1 units of product ', ','),
            ' ', ''),
        1, 2, '')
FROM
    @Table AS T
```

Results:

```
Replaced
1111111
2222222,33333333,55555555,44444444
7676767
0909090,36456421
```

Comment: What will happen if it will say "2 units of products"?

Comment: It won't be replaced of course. This shows how important a complete and meaningful example is when posting a question (if there might be these values) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING(string, start, length)`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Your_value, 41) AS ExtractString;
```

Example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING("Successfully refunded 1 units of product 11111111", 41) AS ExtractString;
```

Comment: what about subsequent rows? You are suggesting to write a separate substring expression for each row, not a good solution.

Comment: yes you can use it like  SELECT SUBSTRING(`email`,4) FROM `users`

Comment: "Successfully refunded 1 units of product" is in your every row so you can use it

Answer (score 0):

If the product code is always the same length, then you can simply do:

```
select right(col, 8) as product_code
```

If the string may not look like this, then use `case`:

```
select (case when col like '% product %'  -- or whatever
             then right(col, 8)
        end) as product_code
```

If you want what comes after `'product'`:

```
select stuff(col, 1, charindex('product', col) + 7, '') as product_code
```